# Definitions of XCode project templates, and approaches to Cocoa development

Tags: cocoa, xcode

My background is c#, .net, and Visual Studio.

I've been trying to get to grips with Cocoa development, but am finding it hard to find information about certain things, maybe because I'm coming in from a Visual Studio perspective.

A few questions:

1. What's the difference between a "Framework" project, and a "Library" project in XCode?
2. What are the consequences of choosing "dynamic" or "static" for your project when starting a new XCode project. Can this be changed later on? does it affect the contents of the project?
3. Does XCode have the concept of a "solution" with various projects like Visual Studio? If so, how do you reference projects with each other which are in the same solution in XCode?
4. Is it even right to approach a Cocoa project in the same way as a .net one. For example, if I was going to build a simple image manipulation app, I'd start with the core library, which could be referenced in a winforms, silverlight, or an MVC frontend app. How does that organisation work in XCode?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. A Framework project builds a Framework, and a Library projects builds a Library.  A Framework (.framework) is the means by which a library and its associated header files are bundled together in one package (similar to the way an executable and its sundry files are bundled together into a .app package).  If you're building a library which you intend to use in multiple Cocoa projects, or distribute to other developers for that purpose, a Framework is probably the most convenient way to do so.
2. A static library (.a) is analogous to a .lib file in Windows.  It's compiled code which you can link into your executable.  A dynamic library (.dylib) is analogous to a .dll in Windows.  It's compiled code which can be dynamically loaded by your executable.  You can change the output from one to the other after you create it (see the Mach-O Type field under Linking in the Build tab of Project Info.  However, there are probably other settings which would vary between the two.  My advice would be to decide which you want to make, make the project for that, and don't change it.
3. Yes, you can build multiple things from an Xcode Project.  An Xcode project is exactly analogous to a Visual Studio Solution.  What Visual Studio calls Projects, Xcode calls Targets.  So an Xcode project can have multiple targets.  Say, one for a Framework, one for an application that uses that framework, one for a suite of unit tests, etc.  Make yourself an Xcode project, and right click Targets->Add->New Target, and you can play around with it.  Each Target has its own build settings, files, etc.
4. My background is more the MFC/C++ side of the Visual Studio house than the .NET/C# one, but to my knowledge, what you describe is possible, even desirable, in Xcode, sure.  My projects have thus far never been large enough, nor the code amongst them common enough, to bother having a separate library for core functionality, but there's no reason you couldn't do that.

Comment: +1 great answer! thanks zpasternack. I've got just a few further questions but I'll come back a little later after work. cheers again